# Excel opens at top of sheet only

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

How can I get Excel (using Office 365) to open where I left off (usually the bottom) and not the top of the sheet? I have a large spreadsheet and usually need to add new information at the bottom.  When I open the sheet, my view and cursor are always at the top.  I have to scroll down to the bottom every time. The Edit directly in cell box is checked off.

Answer (score 1):

> usually need to add new information at the bottom

#### Keyboard Shortcuts

You can use keyboard shortcuts to jump around in Excel and Sheets.  Might seem like a pain to remember but they become pretty automatic.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>
   This works best if you have mostly contiguous data

   - jumps to the last row in a contiguous group of values,
   - jumps to the first value/row of the next group, if already
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>    <kbd>↓</kbd>    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
   This works best if your data has a lot of gaps and will always take you to the last populated row

   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> jumps to the cell at the intersection of the last populated row and the last populated column.  The cell it jumps to may not itself be populated.
   - <kbd>↓</kbd> moves down one row (empty row)
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> jumps to the first column since there is data in the row.
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
   Jumps to cell `A1`

#### VBA

This code will use VBA to populate Cell A1 of each tab in your spreadsheet with a hyperlink to the last cell that was edited (except for cell A1 which is ignored ;-).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim r As Excel.Range
  Set r = Me.Range("A1")
 
  Dim url As String
  url = """[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Target.Address & """, ""Last edited: " & Target.Address & """"
 
  If Application.Intersect(Target(1), r) Is Nothing Then
    Range("A1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & url & ")"

  End If

End Sub
```

<sup>**Example of VBA** 

[image]</sup>

<sup>**Examples of** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd></sup>
[image]
**Example of** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>    <kbd>↓</kbd>    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a command in VBA to have your workbook open to a specific sheet and cell. To access visual basic (VBA) press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. After that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to pull up the area to access the code for your sheets. Find the sheet you want to apply this change to and either right click and select "view code" or double click on that sheet.

From there, you will want to copy and paste this code into the large white area on the screen.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

This will open the workbook to the cell in the "Range" argument. You can change this to a specific cell like CD1025 for example and your code will look like this.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("CD1025"), True

End Sub
```

This ensures that whenever you open the workbook, cell CD1025 will be the cell that appears in the top left corner of your screen.